# Kartik yii2-mpdf: gridview grouping doesn't work

Tags: yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I'm using [Kartik yii2-mpdf](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf) exporter to export a yii2 page. This page uses the Kartik GridView and the group option for a column (`'group'=>true`). The page looks like this: http://demos.krajee.com/group-grid-demo/2 (the build in exporter in this demo works)

When i use kartik mpdf exporter the columns just don't get grouped; displaying the page in the browser works.

I was wondering, how to make the group within the pdf.

***UPDATE:***

mpdf is rendering rows with rowspan correctly. so the problem i had was actual the data i provided for the gridview. Kartik's GridView is modifying the output with js to show up the rowspan correctly. So i build the table on my own, through looping through the data. A good example what is working with yii2-mpdf can be found [here](https://github.com/kartik-v/mpdf/blob/master/examples/example05_tables.php).

Besides this, i'm really wondering, how the export into pdf within [kartik group grid](http://demos.krajee.com/group-grid-demo/2) is working?

Comment: Mpdf doesn't work the way you think. You can not just export a Gridview like that. mpdf doesn't support many CSS properties. Please go and read the mpdf's [doc](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html).

Comment: well, i can export a gridview like that; the result isn't just not the same. Somehow your response didn't really help me here. sry.